# I am making up a bottle for you

Tags: vocabulary

When you are preparing baby formula to your baby. Can we say,

> Just wait a minute, I am ***making up*** a bottle for you.

For coffee, we say make a cup of coffee.

How about formula milk, what vocabulary to say you are making the milk?

Comment: "I'm preparing a bottle for you."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sentence is not correct, mostly due to the broad use of the term "making up". The best change would be to drop 'up':

> Just wait a minute, I am **making** a bottle

It is important to understand that although you are not making the milk itself, it is implied that you are preparing the bottle.

Answer (score 3):

*Making up* isn't right.  That's the kind of thing you would do when someone asks you a question to which you don't know the answer — you *make up* an answer.  (Besides **fabricating something from nothing**, some other less relevant meanings of *make up* include applying cosmetics, taking an exam after everyone else took it on the scheduled date, and reconciling after an argument.)

***Making a bottle*** could work.  ***Preparing a bottle*** would be even better.

*Making the milk* wouldn't be quite right, though.  That's a process that happens in the mother's mammary glands.